# jQuery to fadeIn and fadeOut based upon scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following to change an element's opacity from 0 to 1 based upon the number of pixels they have scrolled and it works perfectly.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
      $("#hook").stop().animate({
          opacity: 1
      }, 300);
  } else {
      $("#hook").stop().animate({
          opacity: 0
      }, 300);
  }
});
```

What I would like to add is something that says, "when the user has scrolled 500 pixels or more, fade it back out."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I missing something? That code is 99% there! http://jsfiddle.net/AwnWe/2

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log('Scroll ', scrollTop);
  if (scrollTop > 500 || scrollTop < 200) {
      $("#hook").stop().animate({
          opacity: 0
      }, 300);
  } else {
      $("#hook").stop().animate({
          opacity: 1
      }, 300);
  }
});​
```

Comment: It seems opacity value should be interchanged from `0` to `1` and `1` to `0` then it is working fine. FYI **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/expyP/1/)**

Comment: He says, "when the user has scrolled 500 pixels or more, fade it back out."

Comment: @SivaCharan Your example doesn't show anything fading since the div moves off the screen

Comment: @bygrace Ok, my brain hurts now, but yes, you are correct and I did not misread it initially.

Comment: Only thing I would change is breaking out the function that the scroll is binding to and call it on page load so that it will initially be faded out since scroll is < 200. Or set its opacity to 0 by default via css.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could probably change `$(this).scrollTop() > 200` to `$(this).scrollTop() > 200 && $(this).scrollTop() < 500`

Comment: FYI, I would break out the function you bind to the scroll event and fire it on page load so that your '#hook' will be hidden initially.

Comment: Most JS developers don't usually name functions starting with a capital letter, unless it's a constructor (Your FadeInOut).

Comment: Yeah I know, I was just doing C# all day and I'm used to uppercase for that.